# How to make pure css floating tooltips (absolutely positioned span) dynamically resize to accommodate text

Tags: html, css, tooltip

I recently had an idea for using the CSS pseudo-class `:hover` to display a styled tooltip when the mouse is hovered over a link.

The basic code for the link looks like this:

```css
.hasTooltip {
    position:relative;
}
.hasTooltip span {
    display:none;
}

.hasTooltip:hover span {
    display:block;
    background-color:black;
    border-radius:5px;
    color:white;
    box-shadow:1px 1px 3px gray;
    position:absolute;
    padding:5px;
    top:1.3em;
    left:0px;   
    max-width:200px; /* I don't want the width to be too large... */
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="hasTooltip">This link has a tooltip!<span>This is the tooltip text!</span></a>
```

[The result is exactly what I want](http://jsfiddle.net/techappetite/9jaZL/), but with one annoying problem: the span does not expand to accommodate text, and if I don't specify a width, the text is squashed.

I did some searching on Google, found a couple examples of work people had done ([this example](http://lixlpixel.org/css_tooltip/) is creepily similar to what I've gotten), but no one seems to have addressed the `span` width problem I'm having.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I know this answer is extremely late, but it appears the key to your issue would be to use:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

inside of your span, and get rid of any sort of width definition.  Of course the drawback to this will be that the tooltip will only be able to support a single line.  If you want a multiline solution you will most likely have to use javascript.

Here is an example of of this method:
http://jsbin.com/oxamez/1/edit

An added bonus is that this works all the way down to IE7. If you do not need to support IE7, I would suggest folding the span, and img styles into a :before, and :after for the .tooltip. Then you can populate the text using the data-* attribute.

Comment: Wow, great solution... thanks! +1 for the awesome example as well.

Comment: I only need to support single line, so this solution works great!, do you have an explanation why white-space: nowrap should be used though?

Comment: If you don't use the 'nowrap' the text will wrap to the width of the widest word in the string. Since the tooltip is set as a display of block when activated, and has no set width, ad defaults to be as narrow as possible. 'nowrap' allows the tooltip to always be as wide as the text it contains.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think there's a perfect solution to this problem with pure CSS. The first problem is that when you place the `span` inside the `a` tag the `span` only wants to expand as far as the width of the link. If you place the `span` after the the `a` it's possible to get close to what you're trying to do but you'll have to set the `margin-top: 1.3em` and then have to set a negative margin to slide the tooltip left. However, it's going to be a fixed setting so it won't sit exactly at the start of each link.

I whipped up a jQuery solution that sets `left` dynamically (and a nice little fade effect for good measure).

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wdm954/9jaZL/7/

```
$('.hasTooltip').hover(function() {
    var offset = $(this).offset();
    $(this).next('span').fadeIn(200).addClass('showTooltip');
    $(this).next('span').css('left', offset.left + 'px');
}, function() {
    $(this).next('span').fadeOut(200);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Although I was looking for a pure CSS solution (and I have a fairly decent idea of how to do this via JavaScript), I'm accepting your answer since you went the extra mile to explain why it is next to impossible to do what I want to do via CSS, but that it is possible with some jQuery magic.
Thanks for the demo, too... it's very helpful! :D

Answer (score 1):

These tool tips can also be integrated into a word press theme easily. Just copy the CSS into your style. Css file and when creating your posts, just take help of the HTML code and create your own tool tips. Rest is all styling, which can be altered according to your own choice. You may also use images inside the tool tip boxes.

http://www.handycss.com/how/how-to-create-a-pure-css-tooltip/

Answer (score 0):

Even though this question is a bit older already, I would suggest the following compromise:
Just use max-width: 200px; and min-width: 300%; or so,
whereas the min-width could result higher than the max-width.
Just figure it out.
This way you could not have entirely liquid tooltips but the width would stand in kind of a correlation with the width of the containing link element.
In terms of optical pleasantness this approach could be of value.

---

*edit*:
Well I must admit it is nonsense what I wrote. When the min-width can be higher than the max-width, there is no sense to it.
So just putting the min-width in percent would achieve what I tried to suggest.
Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

I found this and it was working for me. It's a good solution when you have a lot of elements and jquery plugins on the same page and you can't work with

```
<a href="#">Text <span>Tooltip</span></a>
```

View pure CSS solution: [JS BIN](http://jsbin.com/owupil/10/edit)

Credit to [trezy.com](http://trezy.com/blog/pure-css-tooltips-now-with-more-awesome/)